# How TO - Toggle: Hide Multiple and Show One section?

Tags: javascript, button, toggle, show-hide, sections

I have a page with several buttons and each button has its one information to show, I need to show one button information and hide others with a button click.

I tried this code, I expect sec2 appears and all section with class name "section" be hidden, the sec2 toggle with click, but the others section don't hide.

```
<button class="button1" onclick="myFunction1();hide()"></button>

<style>

.button1 {
background-image: url("http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP9885.jpg"); padding:65% 50%; 
 background-position: center;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border-radius: 0px;

}

.section {
display: none;
}

</style>

<script>
    function myFunction1() {
  var section = document.getElementById("sec1");
  if (section.style.display === "none") {
    section.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    section.style.display = "none";
  }


    function hide() {
  var section = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
  if (clicked) { section.style.display = 'none'
  }

    }
```

html in inspector page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    ...
  <style id="wpr_lightbox_styles">
    .lg-backdrop {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
    }

    .lg-toolbar, .lg-dropdown {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
    }

    .lg-dropdown:after {
        border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
    }

    .lg-sub-html {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
    }

    .lg-thumb-outer, .lg-progress-bar {
        background-color: #444444 !important;
    }

    .lg-progress {
        background-color: #a90707 !important;
    }

    .lg-icon {
        color: #efefef !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
    }

    .lg-icon.lg-toogle-thumb {
        font-size: 24px !important;
    }

    .lg-icon:hover, .lg-dropdown-text:hover {
        color: #ffffff !important;
    }

    .lg-sub-html, .lg-dropdown-text {
        color: #efefef !important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
    }

    #lg-counter {
        color: #efefef !important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
    }

    .lg-prev, .lg-next {
        font-size: 35px !important;
    }/* Defaults */

    .lg-icon {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    #lg-counter {
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .lg-thumb-outer {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    .lg-thumb-item {
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        border: none !important;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .lg-thumb-item.active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="page-template ...">
 ...

                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <style>
                    /*! elementor - v3.7.0 - 08-08-2022 */
                    .elementor-heading-title {
                        padding: 0;
                        margin: 0;
                        line-height:1
                    }

                    .elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title[class * =elementor-size-] > a {
                        color: inherit;
                        font-size: inherit;
                        line-height:inherit
                    }

                    .elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-small {
                        font-size:15px
                    }

                    .elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-medium {
                        font-size:19px
                    }

                    .elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-large {
                        font-size:29px
                    }

                    .elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xl {
                        font-size:39px
                    }

                    .elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xxl {
                        font-size: 59px
                    }
                    </style>
                    <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Objetos</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="elementor-element elementor-element-6f3cdd88 section e-container--column e-container" data-id="6f3cdd88" data-element_type="container" id="sec1" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8b7a9c4 zoomcol e-container--row e-container" data-id="8b7a9c4" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-3b62caa7 imgzoom e-container--column e-container" data-id="3b62caa7" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}"></div>
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-25158a18 e-container--column e-container" data-id="25158a18" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2763791e elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="2763791e" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-container"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="elementor-element elementor-element-0578a88 section e-container--column e-container" data-id="0578a88" data-element_type="container" id="sec2" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c715813 zoomcol e-container--row e-container" data-id="c715813" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-0e9dcd0 imgzoom e-container--column e-container" data-id="0e9dcd0" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}"></div>
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8d8cb29 e-container--column e-container" data-id="8d8cb29" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-804a190 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="804a190" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-container"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-5e0c439 e-container--column e-container" data-id="5e0c439" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-3a708f9 e-container--row e-container" data-id="3a708f9" data-element_type="container">
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-d08c2ab e-container--column e-container" data-id="d08c2ab" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-80a8f33 elementor-widget elementor-widget-html" data-id="80a8f33" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="html.default">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <button class="button1" onclick="myFunction1()"></button>

                            <style>
                            .button1 {
                                background-image: url("http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP9885.jpg");
                                padding: 65% 50%;
                                background-position: center;
                                background-size: 100%;
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                border-radius: 0px;
                            }
                            </style>

                            <script>
                            function myFunction1() {
                                var section = document.getElementById("sec1");
                                if (section.style.display === "none") {
                                    section.style.display = "block";
                                } else {
                                    section.style.display = "none";
                                }

                            }
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-99c896b e-container--column e-container" data-id="99c896b" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-0316978 elementor-widget elementor-widget-html" data-id="0316978" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="html.default">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <button class="button2" onclick="myFunction2()"></button>

                            <style>
                            .button2 {
                                background-image: url("http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP9854.jpg");
                                padding: 65% 50%;
                                background-position: center;
                                background-size: 100%;
                                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                border-radius: 0px;
                            }
                            </style>

                            <script>
                            function myFunction2() {
                                var section = document.getElementById("sec2");
                                if (section.style.display === "none") {
                                    section.style.display = "block";
                                } else {
                                    section.style.display = "none";
                                }

                            }
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-a43b1b7 e-container--column e-container" data-id="a43b1b7" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c62d904 elementor-widget__width-inherit showme1649 elementor-widget elementor-widget-global elementor-global-5791 elementor-widget-image" data-id="c62d904" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <figure class="wp-caption">
                                <img decoding="async" width="1813" height="2421" src="https://i0.wp.com/s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP1731-copy.jpg?fit=1813%2C2421" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="objeto de coleção" loading="lazy" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP1731-copy.jpg?w=1813 1813w, https://i0.wp.com/s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP1731-copy.jpg?resize=225%2C300 225w, https://i0.wp.com/s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP1731-copy.jpg?resize=767%2C1024 767w, https://i0.wp.com/s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP1731-copy.jpg?resize=768%2C1026 768w, https://i0.wp.com/s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP1731-copy.jpg?resize=1150%2C1536 1150w, https://i0.wp.com/s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP1731-copy.jpg?resize=1534%2C2048 1534w, https://i0.wp.com/s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMGP1731-copy.jpg?w=1600 1600w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"/>
                                <figcaption class="widget-image-caption wp-caption-text">CAI_1649</figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-0ab2618 e-container--column e-container" data-id="0ab2618" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">
                    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-419f77e showme1554 elementor-widget elementor-widget-global elementor-global-5794 elementor-widget-image" data-id="419f77e" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default">
                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <figure class="wp-caption">
                                <img decoding="async" 
...
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/jetpack/11.5.1/_inc/build/photon/photon.min.js' id='jetpack-photon-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/7.1.0/assets/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js' id='jquery-blockui-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/7.1.0/assets/js/js-cookie/js.cookie.min.js' id='js-cookie-js'></script>
    <script id='woocommerce-js-extra'>
    var woocommerce_params = {
        "ajax_url": "\/...};
    </script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/7.1.0/assets/js/frontend/woocommerce.min.js' id='woocommerce-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/7.1.0/assets/js/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js' id='jquery-cookie-js'></script>
    <script id='wc-cart-fragments-js-extra'>
    var wc_cart_fragments_params = {
        "ajax_url": "..."
    };
    </script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/woo-poly-integration/public/js/Cart.min.js?ver=1.5.0' id='wc-cart-fragments-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/royal-elementor-addons/assets/js/lib/particles/particles.js?ver=3.0.6' id='wpr-particles-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/royal-elementor-addons/assets/js/lib/jarallax/jarallax.min.js?ver=1.12.7' id='wpr-jarallax-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/royal-elementor-addons/assets/js/lib/parallax/parallax.min.js?ver=1.0' id='wpr-parallax-hover-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor/assets/js/hello-frontend.min.js?ver=1.0.0' id='hello-theme-frontend-js'></script>
    <script id='eael-general-js-extra'>
    var localize = {...}
        }
    };
    </script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/assets/front-end/js/view/general.min.js?ver=5.4.4' id='eael-general-js'></script>
    <script id='wc-country-select-js-extra'>
    var wc_country_select_params = {
        "countries": "{...}}",
        "i18n_select_state_text": "Selecione uma op\u00e7\u00e3o\u2026",
        "i18n_no_matches": "Nenhuma combina\u00e7\u00e3o foi encontrada",
        "i18n_ajax_error": "O carregando falhou",
        "i18n_input_too_short_1": "Digite 1 ou mais caracteres",
        "i18n_input_too_short_n": "Digite %qty% ou mais caracteres",
        "i18n_input_too_long_1": "Exclua 1 caracter",
        "i18n_input_too_long_n": "Exclua %qty% caracteres",
        "i18n_selection_too_long_1": "Voc\u00ea pode apenas selecionar 1 item",
        "i18n_selection_too_long_n": "Voc\u00ea pode apenas selecionar %qty% itens",
        "i18n_load_more": "Carregando mais resultados\u2026",
        "i18n_searching": "Procurando\u2026"
    };
    </script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/7.1.0/assets/js/frontend/country-select.min.js' id='wc-country-select-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/kangu/assets/js/shipping-calculator.js?ver=6.1.1' id='shipping-calculator-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/kangu/assets/js/kangu-cart.js?ver=6.1.1' id='kangu-cart-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/js/webpack-pro.runtime.min.js?ver=3.7.0' id='elementor-pro-webpack-runtime-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/webpack.runtime.min.js?ver=3.7.0' id='elementor-webpack-runtime-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/frontend-modules.min.js?ver=3.7.0' id='elementor-frontend-modules-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/c/6.1.1/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/regenerator-runtime.min.js' id='regenerator-runtime-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/c/6.1.1/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/wp-polyfill.min.js' id='wp-polyfill-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/c/6.1.1/wp-includes/js/dist/hooks.min.js' id='wp-hooks-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/c/6.1.1/wp-includes/js/dist/i18n.min.js' id='wp-i18n-js'></script>
    <script id='wp-i18n-js-after'>
    wp.i18n.setLocaleData({
        'text direction\u0004ltr': ['ltr']
    });
    </script>
    <script id='elementor-pro-frontend-js-before'>
    var ElementorProFrontendConfig = {
        "ajaxurl": "http:\/\/s910698169.onlinehome.us\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php",
        "nonce": "39757b426d",
        "urls": {
            "assets": "http:\/\/s910698169.onlinehome.us\/wp-content\/plugins\/elementor-pro\/assets\/",
            "rest": "http:\/\/s910698169.onlinehome.us\/wp-json\/"
        }
...

    </script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/js/frontend.min.js?ver=3.7.0' id='elementor-pro-frontend-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js?ver=4.0.2' id='elementor-waypoints-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/c/6.1.1/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js' id='jquery-ui-core-js'></script>
    <script id='elementor-frontend-js-before'>
    var elementorFrontendConfig = {
        "environmentMode": {
            "edit": false,
            "wpPreview": false,
            "isScriptDebug": false
        },
        "i18n": {...}
            }
        },
        "version": "3.7.0",
        "is_static": false,
        "experimentalFeatures": {
            "e_dom_optimization": true,
            "e_optimized_assets_loading": true,
            "e_optimized_css_loading": true,
            "e_font_icon_svg": true,
            "a11y_improvements": true,
            "additional_custom_breakpoints": true,
            "e_import_export": true,
            "e_hidden_wordpress_widgets": true,
            "container": true,
            "theme_builder_v2": true,
            "hello-theme-header-footer": true,
            "landing-pages": true,
            "elements-color-picker": true,
            "favorite-widgets": true,
            "admin-top-bar": true,
            "page-transitions": true,
            "notes": true,
            "form-submissions": true,
            "e_scroll_snap": true
        },
        "urls": {
            "assets": "..."
        },
        "settings": {
            "page": [],
            "editorPreferences": []
        },
        "kit": {
            "viewport_tablet": 750,
            "body_background_background": "classic",
            "viewport_mobile": 350,
            "active_breakpoints": ["viewport_mobile", "viewport_mobile_extra", "viewport_tablet", "viewport_tablet_extra", "viewport_laptop", "viewport_widescreen"],
            "viewport_mobile_extra": 450,
            "viewport_tablet_extra": 1000,
            "viewport_laptop": 1300,
            "viewport_widescreen": 1301,
            "global_image_lightbox": "yes",
            "lightbox_enable_fullscreen": "yes",
            "lightbox_enable_zoom": "yes",
            "woocommerce_notices_elements": [],
            "hello_header_logo_type": "logo",
            "hello_header_menu_layout": "horizontal"
        },
        "post": {
            "id": 5782,
            "title": "...",
            "excerpt": "",
            "featuredImage": "..."
        }
    };
    </script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/frontend.min.js?ver=3.7.0' id='elementor-frontend-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/js/elements-handlers.min.js?ver=3.7.0' id='pro-elements-handlers-js'></script>
    <script id='wpr-addons-js-js-extra'>
    var WprConfig = {
        "ajaxurl": "http:\/\/s910698169.onlinehome.us\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php",
        "resturl": "http:\/\/s910698169.onlinehome.us\/wp-json\/wpraddons\/v1",
        "nonce": "275ea4769c"
    };
    </script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/royal-elementor-addons/assets/js/frontend.min.js?ver=1.3.55' id='wpr-addons-js-js'></script>
    <script src='http://s910698169.onlinehome.us/wp-content/plugins/royal-elementor-addons/assets/js/modal-popups.min.js?ver=1.3.55' id='wpr-modal-popups-js-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/7.1.0/assets/js/zoom/jquery.zoom.min.js' id='zoom-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/7.1.0/assets/js/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.min.js' id='flexslider-js'></script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/c/6.1.1/wp-includes/js/underscore.min.js' id='underscore-js'></script>
    <script id='wp-util-js-extra'>
    var _wpUtilSettings = {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"
        }
    };
    </script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/c/6.1.1/wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js' id='wp-util-js'></script>
    <script id='wc-add-to-cart-variation-js-extra'>
    var wc_add_to_cart_variation_params = {
        "wc_ajax_url": "\/?wc-ajax=%%endpoint%%&elementor_page_id=5782",
        "i18n_no_matching_variations_text": "Desculpe, nenhum produto atende sua sele\u00e7\u00e3o. Escolha uma combina\u00e7\u00e3o diferente.",
        "i18n_make_a_selection_text": "Selecione uma das op\u00e7\u00f5es do produto antes de adicion\u00e1-lo ao carrinho.",
        "i18n_unavailable_text": "Desculpe, este produto n\u00e3o est\u00e1 dispon\u00edvel. Escolha uma combina\u00e7\u00e3o diferente."
    };
    </script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/7.1.0/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js' id='wc-add-to-cart-variation-js'></script>
    <script id='wc-single-product-js-extra'>
    var wc_single_product_params = {
        "i18n_required_rating_text": "Selecione uma classifica\u00e7\u00e3o",
        "review_rating_required": "yes",
        "flexslider": {
            "rtl": false,
            "animation": "slide",
            "smoothHeight": true,
            "directionNav": true,
            "controlNav": "thumbnails",
            "slideshow": false,
            "animationSpeed": 500,
            "animationLoop": false,
            "allowOneSlide": false
        },
        "zoom_enabled": "1",
        "zoom_options": [],
        "photoswipe_enabled": "",
        "photoswipe_options": {
            "shareEl": false,
            "closeOnScroll": false,
            "history": false,
            "hideAnimationDuration": 0,
            "showAnimationDuration": 0
        },
        "flexslider_enabled": "1"
    };
    </script>
    <script src='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/7.1.0/assets/js/frontend/single-product.min.js' id='wc-single-product-js'></script>
    <script src='https://stats.wp.com/e-202248.js' defer></script>
    <script>
    _stq = window._stq || [];
    _stq.push(['view', {
        v: 'ext',
        blog: '208049155',
        post: '5782',
        tz: '-3',
        srv: 's910698169.onlinehome.us',
        j: '1:11.5.1'
    }]);
    _stq.push(['clickTrackerInit', '208049155', '5782']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `getElementsByClassName()` and `querySelectorAll()` return an array of elements (an HTMLCollection for `getElementsByClassName()` and a NodeList for `querySelectorAll()`).

This means trying to apply something like the `style` attribute to it doesn't work because you haven't specified which element in the array will be updated.

Also, because the returned list of elements in an array, you can easily iterate through all of them using `forEach()` to set their visibility to ***hidden***.

Your HTML isn't included so I can only show you the changes for your `hide()` function.

```
const hide = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".section").forEach(el => el.style.visibility = "hidden")
}
```

#### NOTES

It looks like you are using a separate function to toggle each section. While you have not included your HTML, it is very likely that you could merge both the show and hide function into one function for all buttons/sections. This is typically done by adding an event listener to each button that then uses your document/HTML structure to determine which sections to show or hide. But again, you would need to post your HTML for me to know how it is structured and thus how the functions could be merged/optimized.

Comment: I updated the question with all I have write in code... I'm using Wordpress with the plugin Elementor.. so html is inside the plugin, I didn't write it, I can only make addiction with code, names and styles.. 

So, I named the sections with the same same in class name and particular names in ID...

Comment: @Fabi Can you include any of the HTML just as an example? You can use the browser's inspector (`F12`) to copy the HTML or use the '**View Source**' option in the right-click menu of your browser to view the HTML. The actual HTML is important, even if it is just a small sample as ***how*** the elements are organized and structured matters. If I can see some of the HTML I can determine exactly how to create a **show/hide** function for any/all buttons.

Comment: Hello, I just updated with the code that is shown in the inspector page, I don't know if it's too weird... Please, let me know if you can see some solution with this... thank you very much

Comment: I just found a plugin that works for what I need at the moment! "Dynamic Visibility", the free version is exactly what I need now... Thank you for your time.. anyway I will keep studding, this subject interest me a lot